# How to use Bootstrap with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, I am trying to use Bootstrap with Laravel but it is very difficult to use with it.

```
Form::submit('save',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'));
```

This is the syntax used for the bootstrap styling. If we are using this every time we have to write bootstrap class name by ourself there is no auto-complete syntax intellisense. This is not the case in CodeIgniter. So  if any one know how we can gain auto-complete classes of bootstrap with Laravel syntax please tell me.

Comment: This sounds more like you have an issue with your editor than with actual programming, or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: It really sounds like `copy->paste` isn't a viable option. But in all seriousness, what editor is causing this problem? You can most like assign keyboard shortcuts to insert code snippets, such as in Netbeans or Sublime Text

Comment: I dont know at all. But I search on google and I have install plugin for Laravel but there is no auto-complete syntax of Bootstrap in PHPstorm for the Laravel Form tags. I am new please help.

Comment: Ah, so the question is about PHPStorm? You should definitely write that in the question then, and also add it as a tag.

Comment: He is trying to use the Bootstrap front-end framework and hook into Laravel form builders (which generate your HTML for you therefore not using Bootstrap HTML)...  He needs to get Laravel to add the proper classes that bootstrap uses for styling forms.  It's not so much a PHPstorm question.

Comment: Thank you Joey for understanding my problem. You are great. My problem is solved with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use purely the laravel form helpers (except the opening and closing as that produces the required CRF tokens)

```
{{ Form::open() }}
<div class="text-left" style="font-width:100;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="your@email.address" value="{{Input::old('email')}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Name</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" required="required" name="name" id="inputName" placeholder="Hoo Beau" value="{{Input::old('name')}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTel">Phone</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="tel" id="inputTel" placeholder="555.655.4555" value="{{Input::old('tel')}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputMsg">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="inputMsg" required="required" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Whats up?">{{Input::old('message')}}</textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: It means we can use simple div style code inside the Laravel Blade template Form Helpers ?? Is it Good practice ?? @joey

Comment: It's perfectly fine practice to do this.  Laravel template helpers and form helpers are just there to help you, you can use the label and input generators if it is easier for you... It does make for cleaner (and shorter) code.

Comment: Thank you Joey for understanding my problem. You are great. My problem is solved with your solution.

Comment: That was in Laravel version 4 that allowed you to flash the posted input to a new view after you may have redirected the page and processed the data.  You would still need to pass the flashed input into the view using ->withInput() I believe.   Here, the docs explain it way better: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#old-input  .  Now I believe the method is: ->flash() in 5.1